Double integral $ \iint_D (x^4-y^4) dx\,dy$
I have troubles with the following integral
$$
\iint_D (x^4-y^4) dx\,dy
$$
over D: $1<x^2-y^2<4, \sqrt{17}<x^2+y^2<5, x<0, y>0$
This is the same problem as in Compute $\iint_D (x^4-y^4) \,dx\,dy$
where my problem is that I cannot solve the following expression with $u=x^2+y^2, v=x^2-y^2$
$$
\int_1^4 \int_{\sqrt{17}}^5 \frac{uv}{4\sqrt{u^2-v^2}} dudv = \frac{1}{4}\int_1^4 \bigg[ v\sqrt{u^2-v^2} \bigg]_{\sqrt{17}}^5 dv = ?
$$
since
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial u} v\sqrt{u^2-v^2} = \frac{uv}{\sqrt{u^2-v^2}}
$$
What am I missing? Any suggestions?
Thanks.
Sincerely, TS

Where did you get the $4$ in the upper bound for $v$?

I did a mistake in the post, D include $1<x^2-y^2<4$.

Try to use polar coordinates, you have to integrate $r^4(2sin^2(t)-1)$

Plug in $u=\sqrt{17}$ and $u=5$. The subsequent integrals w.r.t. $v$ are just as trivial as the one you computed.

I have and I don't obtain the correct answer. $$ \frac{1}{4} \int_1^4 \bigg[ v \sqrt{u^2-v^2} \bigg]_{\sqrt{17}}^5 dv = \frac{1}{4} \int_1^4 v \sqrt{25-v^2}-v \sqrt{17-v^2} dv = \frac{1}{4} \bigg[ - \frac{(25-v^2)^{3/2}}{3} \bigg]_1^4 - \frac{1}{4} \bigg[ - \frac{(17-v^2)^{3/2}}{3} \bigg]_1^4 = \frac{1}{4} \bigg( -\frac{(25-16)^{3/2}}{3} -- \frac{(25-1)^{3/2}}{3} \bigg) - \frac{1}{4} \bigg( -\frac{(17-16)^{3/2}}{3} -- \frac{(17-1)^{3/2}}{3} \bigg) \neq \frac{1}{2}(8 \sqrt{6}-15) = solution
$$
Any suggestion? Thx.

Your answer is numerically equal to $\frac{1}{2}(8\sqrt{6}-15)$.

As a matter of fact, your answer $=\frac{1}{12}(-9^{3/2}+24^{3/2}+1-16^{3/2})=\frac{1}{12}(-27+48\sqrt{6}+1-64)=\frac{1}{12}(48\sqrt{6}-90)=\frac{1}{2}(8\sqrt{6}-15).$

Thank you very much, I did a mistake on the power of 24.
